# Controls that don't render any HTML

Tags: html, asp.net, tags, controls, webbrowser-control

Am very new to ASP.NET.

I know that all the server controls are rendered as HTML controls on the browser.

So, My question is, are there any ASP.NET Controls that don't render any HTML on the browser ??

I googled and found `PlaceHolder` and `Literal` controls don't render anything. Are there any other controls?

Thank you.

Comment: literal controls can render html although any control can be set not to render anything by setting it's visible property to false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are more controls that doesn't render any HTML themselves, like the `ContentPlaceHolder` and `ViewCollection`, and controls that mainly interact with other controls and may or may not render anything themselves, like `SqlDataSource` and `RangeValidator`.

Answer (score 1):

Server controls may or may not render HTML depending on how you use them, for example I use the Literal control to output text to the page and Labels where I want to "associate" text to another control - but essentially HTML output is the same. What is it you are you trying to acheive?